# Problems Running Azure Automation Powershell to Scale Database Back After Restore Operation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to scale back a database after the restore operation has completed and am running into some problems.  I am getting this exception and wonder if there is something in this script not supported by Azure Automation Workflows?

Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

```
workflow insertflowname
{
  <#  
  .SYNOPSIS
```

The purpose of this runbook is to demonstrate how to restore a particular database to a new database using an Azure Automation workflow.  Then it is scaled back to Basic.

```
.NOTES  

#>  


# Specify Azure Subscription Name

$subName = 'insertsubscription name'

# Connect to Azure Subscription
Connect-Azure -AzureConnectionName $subName
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName

# Define source databasename
$SourceDatabaseName = 'insert database name'

# Define source server
$SourceServerName = 'insert source server'

# Define destination server
$TargetServerName = 'insert destination server'

Write-Output "`$SourceServerName [$SourceServerName]"
Write-Output "`$TargetServerName [$TargetServerName]"
Write-Output "`$SourceDatabaseName [$SourceDatabaseName]"

Write-Output "Retrieving recoverable database details for database [$SourceDatabaseName] on server [$SourceServerName]."
$RecoverableDatabase = Get-AzureSqlRecoverableDatabase –ServerName $SourceServerName -DatabaseName $SourceDatabaseName
$TargetDatabaseName = "$SourceDatabaseName-$($RecoverableDatabase.LastAvailableBackupDate.ToString('O'))"
Write-Output "`$TargetDatabaseName [$TargetDatabaseName]"

Write-Output "Starting recovery of database [$SourceDatabaseName] to server [$TargetServerName] as database [$TargetDatabaseName]."
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseRecovery -SourceDatabase $RecoverableDatabase -TargetServerName $TargetServerName –TargetDatabaseName $TargetDatabaseName 

$PollingInterval = 10
Write-Output "Monitoring status of recovery operation, polling every [$PollingInterval] second(s)."
$KeepGoing = $true
while ($KeepGoing) {
    $operation = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseOperation -ServerName $TargetServerName -DatabaseName $TargetDatabaseName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "DATABASE RECOVERY"} | Sort-Object StartTime -Descending
    if ($operation) {
        $operation[0]
        if ($operation[0].State -eq "COMPLETED") { $KeepGoing = $false }
        if ($operation[0].State -eq "FAILED") {
            # Throw error
            $KeepGoing = $false
        }
    } else {
        # Throw error since something went wrong and object was not created
        # May want to have this retry a few times before giving up or at least notify somebody
        # since at this point the recovery has been kicked off and you don't want the database
        # restore to remain at the elevated service level.
        $KeepGoing = $false
    }
    if ($KeepGoing) { Start-Sleep -Seconds $PollingInterval }
}

if ($operation[0].State -eq "COMPLETED") {
    Write-Output "Setting service level for database [$TargetDatabaseName] on server [$TargetServerName] to Basic."
    $ServiceObjective = Get-AzureSQLDatabaseServiceObjective –ServerName $TargetServerName –ServiceObjectiveName "Basic"
    $ServiceObjective
    Set-AzureSqlDatabase –ServerName $TargetServerName –DatabaseName $TargetDatabaseName –Edition "Basic" –ServiceObjective $ServiceObjective -MaxSizeGB 2 –Force
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably hitting the issue described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce6412b8-5cce-4573-befb-6017924ce0d0/whereobject-fails-with-parameter-set-cannot-be-resolved-using-the-specified-named-parameters?forum=azureautomation

Summary:
Use parameter names, don't rely on positional parameters, in PowerShell Workflow. In this case, you need to add the -FilterScript parameter name to Where-Object.